# html - fail to load resource but the file exists

Tags: javascript, html

I’m building a web app and I’m having some trouble with my project not finding certain files when I launch the app.

The files in question are under the babel-poyfill-6-26-0 folder and the mpage folder. I’m adding some libraries to my code under the src folder like such:

[src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJdrb.jpg)

They’re then included in the html header section of view-renderer-controller.js like such:

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Insulin Bolus Calculator</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='./../../mpage/css/cerner-smart-embeddable-lib-1.3.0.min.css'>
        <script src='./../../babel-polyfill-6-26-0/polyfill.min.js'></script>
        <script src='./../../mpage/js/cerner-smart-embeddable-lib-1.3.0.min.js'></script>
    </head>
```

When I build my code, to create the dist folder I copy the folders into new folders in package.json like such:

```
"scripts": {
        "clean": "rm -rf dist/* && rm -rf dist && mkdir dist && mkdir dist/public && mkdir dist/server && mkdir dist/views && rm -f Archive.zip",
        "copy-polyfill": "mkdir dist/babel-polyfill-6-26-0 && cp src/babel-polyfill-6-26-0/* dist/babel-polyfill-6-26-0/",
        "copy-mpage": "mkdir dist/mpage && cp -r src/mpage/* dist/mpage/",
        "copy-public": "cp -r public/* dist/public/ ",
        "build": "npm run lint && npm run clean && npm run test && npm run check-coverage && npm run build-server && npm run build-ui && npm run copy-polyfill && npm run copy-mpage && npm run copy-public && npm run copy-views"
      },
```

Then the dist folder looks like such:
[dist folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIOyl.jpg)

They’re clearly there, but the files still aren’t being found when the app is launched. I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong.

Moreover, I did checked the path of the link in the code and they seem correct.
[path link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60VTT.jpg)

Comment: Can't you change relative paths to absolute? I'm guessing all paths are relative to the views, but maybe they're not at the same level of controller in url.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I ended up copy all the lib to my public then copy it from public to my dist. It is working now. tks! again